# Numerical instability of system of equations of large order polynomials

Tags: python, matrix, numerical-methods, newtons-method

I have a set of non linear polynomials

```
V_n(Input[N])=0
```

where `n` runs from `1` to `N`, with `N` of `Input[N]` unknowns. The `V_n()` contained the polynomial tern of `x**N`. I used the newton's methods to find the roots but encountered the numerical stability issues, part of it contributed from the computation of the matrix inverse. i.e. though `2000**2000=1.1481306952742545242E+6602` was easily computed, the elements taken in matrix inverse were separated by `1E200`, `1E200**2`, were not. This lead to the inverse of matrix multiplication have a large remainders

```
max( Inverse(Jacobian(V_n(Input[N]))) * V_n(Input[N]) )=1E200
```

I've been trying to find the normalization procedure for the newton's method, but with limited progresses. Without the normalization, the root finding algorithm with the newton's method could handle `N~10`, with normalization, this increased `N~50`. However, I needed to compute the system of linear equations at `N~2000`. The good news is the maximum of the roots `max(Input[N])~N` or approximately $N$ itself.

Is there a way to find the roots of this system of equations?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Is `n` the same as `N`? Do you mean with `Input[N]` the whole set of variables `x[1:N]`? Please explain in more words what `V_n` is. Do you mean again the whole set of equations with that one variable? Note that if you have `n` polynomials of degree `d`, then you can get up to `d^n` solutions. Do you want one specific one, any one or all of them? Note that for large values of `n` and `d` it is very unlikely that you will find a solution using Newton's method or any other point iteration.

Comment: @LutzLehmann The small `n` is an indice ranging from `1` to `N` where `N` an integer. `Input[N]` meant the whole set of variables `x[1:N]`. `V_n` is a function takes a vector input `Input[N]` and output a scalar. Let `x` be the largest input value in `Input[N]`, then `V_n(Input[N])~O(x^n)`. It's a set of $N$ equations with $N$ unknowns.

Comment: @njuffa I used the decimal package and set the precession to 200 to 2000+ significant digits. The matrix size `N` seemed to be a bigger issue than the condition of matrix itself. Because the matrix condition was essentially a very large or small number, `x`, which could be resolved through precession packages such as decimal for the simple calculation, but matrix size changed the calculation to be `x^N`, and that broken things easily even for some small `N` such as `N=20`. At this point the solution does appear to be non trivial.